# __callStatic doesn't handle missing static calls

Tags: php, methods, static-methods

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar(){
        echo "Non-static\n";
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        if ($name === 'bar') {
            echo "Static\n";
        }
    }
}

Foo::bar();
```

Class `Foo` does not have a static `bar` method. That is why I was expecting the `Foo::bar()` to be handled by the `__callStatic` method. Unfortunately for me that's not happening for some reason.

The non-static method is being called on `null` instead.

Is it a bug or a feature? How can I make the `__callStatic` to handle that call of a missing static method?

Comment: You have method bar. And can not call this method as static. Thi is logicaly because. You can not have 2 methods in 1 name.

Comment: @Naumov no, the class has no *static* `bar` method. I don't find it logical personally.

Comment: But when you call bar you got call non static method as static error. Becouse bar exist. You can't have in class 2 methods bar. For example `function bar(){}  static function bar(){}` this is erro.