# Invoking a non-static method via the scope resolution operator

Tags: php, methods, static-methods

I've [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388152/callstatic-doesnt-handle-missing-static-calls) some strange (for me) behavior of the PHP interpreter and I'm not sure if it's safe to use it in production or not.

When we call `Foo::bar()` and the `Foo` class does not have the static `bar` method but it has non-static `bar` method, the interpreter will invoke non-static `bar` on `null` (yes, it sounds ridiculous). I expected the `__callStatic` to be invoked in this case. But it's not what is happening for some reason.

I've then found a handy usage for this behavior: to provide the class with static and non-static methods with the same name like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar(){
        if (isset($this)) {
            $this->nonStaticBar();
        } else {
            static::staticBar();
        }
    }

    private function nonStaticBar() {
        echo "Non-static\n";
    }

    private static function staticBar() {
        echo "Static\n";
    }
}

(new Foo())->bar(); // Output: "Non-static"
Foo::bar(); // Output: "Static"
```

Yes I know, that this approach is not elegant and architecturally wrong. The question is if it's safe (standard-compliant) to use this "feature" or not. Are there any other cases when `isset($this)` can equal `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your above example does work, it is not best practice.
This is recognized in the PHP documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.this) and states that in PHP versions before version 7, if `E_STRICT` error reporting is enabled then it will emit the error:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Foo::bar() should not be called statically in /Path/to/file.php on line 22
```

Additionally in PHP versions 7 and above calling static functions statically is deprecated and will cause the following error upon execution:

```
Deprecated:  Non-static method Foo::bar() should not be called statically in /Path/to/file.php on line 22
```

Comment: Thank's for the reference to the docs. I believe that the `__callStatic` must be called in this case. The class does not have the static method with such name. And the docs state that `__callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.`

Comment: @Kolyunya An interesting thing that I noticed when trying to assign/reassign the variable `$this` within a static (or non-static) method is that it will return the fatal error `Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this in /Path/to/file.php`. So, even though it's not best practice, I cannot imagine another case where `isset($this)` would equal `false`.